# How to play single ogv file in IE8 and Safari by HTML5 video?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, safari, html5-video, ogg-theora

How to play single ogv file in IE8 and Safari by HTML5 video?
I known IE and Safari don't support Ogg Theora, but I have a requirement for that.

Any suggestion to me?

Thanks

Comment: hmm, not much to say about this. You know it can't be done, but you have to do it anyway. All I can say is good luck.

Answer (score 2):

OGV.JS: AN OGG THEORA AND VORBIS VIDEO DECODER IN JAVASCRIPT

Targeting Safari 6+ and ie 10+

http://badassjs.com/post/71980473022/ogv-js-an-ogg-theora-and-vorbis-video-decoder-in

Answer (score 1):

IE8 can't play *any* HTML5 video, let alone specific formats. It simply doesn't support it (or any other HTML5 elements). The best you can do is embedding a Flash video. IE9 does support HTML5 video, but still not the OGG Theora format.

Safari explicitly doesn't support it either. It does support HTML5 video, but not the OGG Theora format.

So the short answer is it can't be done. Sorry.

If the requirement is for an open source video format, you might try switching to WebM, which is supported by both Safari and IE9 (although both require the relevant video driver to be installed separately to the browser) as well as Chrome and Firefox. (See http://caniuse.com/#search=video)

IE8 simply isn't going to work for you though, no matter what format you use. It simply doesn't know what the HTML5 video tag is, and there's not much you can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

Cortado streaming applet

Cortado is an open-source cross-browser and cross-platform video playback solution based upon Java technology. Leveraging the huge installation base of Java it allows web-authors to deliver Ogg Theora content without having to worry about the media playback setup installed on customers' machines. This enables e.g. Wikipedia to deliver Ogg Theora video content embedded into articles to millions of users. Originally developed at Fluendo, Cortado's latest versions are now maintained by Xiph.org. If you're interested in using free media delivery technology, e.g. to avoid the costs adjunctive to non-free technologies like H.264, and want to reach a big potential user base, Cortado may be the solution you've been looking for.

http://theora.org/cortado/